# Межпроцессное взаимодействие в macOS

Tags: swift, ipc

Пользователь запускает программу-сервер. В нем он вводит кол-во процессов-клиентов, потом пользователь никак не может взаимодействовать с сервером.  Процесс (клиент) принимает строку от пользователя и с помощью механизмов ipc отправляет ее серверу на обработку - сервер обрабатывает и возвращает обработанную строку обратно. Клиент "одноразовый" - с него можно отправить строку только один раз. Сервер заканчивает работу тогда, когда будут закрыты все клиенты. (У клиента два исхода - либо его сразу закрывают)

Проблема в том, что и сервер и клиенты должны иметь gui. Соответственно c++ здесь отпадает, придется писать на swift и на технологиях, которые его поддерживают.

class Pipe : NSObject здесь односторонний - а использовать такой мне запрещено.

fifo и socket - нужно использовать C.

Какие ipc механизмы вы порекомендуете мне использовать?

Подойдет ли для такой задачи xpc?

Comment: `Соответственно c++ здесь отпадает, придется писать на swift и на технологиях, которые его поддерживают.` почему бы не написать библиотеку на C++ и не подключить к проекту на Swift?

Comment: @schmidt9, а разве так можно? Я знаю лишь то, что можно вставлять си-код прямо в код swift. Вы предлагаете написать IPC на С++,  а интерфейс - на swift и AppKit?

Comment: Напрямую в свифт вставлять си-код по-моему нельзя, хотя с objective c без проблем (objective-c++), тем не менее ничто не мешает в одном проекте использовать swift, objective-c и c++. Правда я не имел дела с IPC, поэтому сложно сказать, в какой мере здесь можно задействовать C++ (если он для вас удобнее) в качестве ядра приложения, хотя например обычный сетевой обмен можно реализовать на Boost

Comment: в целом получается так - в Objective C код C++ можно вставлять напрямую при желании, а для Swift нужны заголовочные файлы и обертки (информации в гугле много)